# Better method of handling navigation flow in app

Tags: blackberry

I have various screens in my app and for each screen which have buttons I have something like the below to push a new screen when a button is clicked -

```
        quizButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {  
             public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {  
                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new CustomScreen());
            }  
        });
```

Just wondering if there is a more 'MVC like' methodology for handling navigation flow ?

Comment: it actually depends on the goal. what makes you think you are doing smth in a wrong/non-optimal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to push a new screen

You can create a class extends MainScreen and also which takes mainscreen object as the argument in the constructor and in the constructor push the next screen according to the flow

So whenever in your project if you are willing to navigate create the object of this custom class and send the screen object as an argument in the constructor

Comment: Thanks, is it a good idea to pop the previous screen off the stack or does it make much of a difference ?

Comment: I would say it is not a good idea to pop the previous screen, but id depends. If you don't pop it, when you click the back button when on the current screen, it will pop the current screen and go to the previous screen. If you don't want this to happen, pop it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `navigationClick` method, not `fieldChanged`. The `fieldChanged` method is called every time the field is focused, unfocused etc. 
The `navigationClick` method is called only when the user clicks on that field, either by touch in storm like devices, or by clicking the trackball/touchpad when the field is focused in non-touch devices.

Comment: @Mugur: Objection! :) I always use `setChangeListener` + `FieldChangeListener` with `ButtonField`s - it works OK.

Comment: Do you use it the same way user470184 uses it or do you have an `if` statement in there? :)

Comment: @Mugur: in most cases it is exactly the way user470184 uses it. :)

Comment: ok, let me give you this use case: You have a screen with a button that says "continue". and you have to go to the next screen when the user **clicks** that button. Then when you're using the FieldChangeListener, would you use the exact same code as in question? Or do you need an `if` in there?

Comment: @Mugur: You are talking in a bit misterious way. :) What exactly are you trying to say? The only field that is changed is the `ButtonField` quizButton itself, so in the `fieldChanged` I don't need to check if the field is actually the quizButton. Also I don't need to check the context param since I don't care about it because the only context for the button is produced by user click (I don't click programmatically). Also check the docs: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html

Comment: @Arhimed: Hmm, now I'm not sure anymore. :) I might have been thinking about the `fieldChangeNotify` method(from TextField) - I've used it recently. But, when I get a few minutes, I'm going to test that bit of code, because now I'm curious. It would seem normal to me that the `fieldChanged` method in the listener would be called when the field **changed** it's state to focused/unfocused, not only when clicked. I'll get back to you. :D